# Decimal is missing after sum of arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sum, decimal

I wanted to add, 1.50 + 2.50 + 3.00 to make 7 and show the decimal value of 7.00

```
NSArray *milkprice;
int sum = 0;
milkprice = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.50",@"2.50",@"3.00", nil];
for (NSDecimalNumber *milk in milkprice)    {


    NSLog (@"list = %@", milkprice);

    sum += [milk integerValue];

    NSLog (@"sum = %ld", (long) sum);

}
    NSLog (@"total = %ld", (long)sum);
```

The NSLog returns 6 instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are many mistakes. Try this:

```
NSArray *milkprice = @[ @"1.50", @"2.50", @"3.00" ];
float sum = 0;
NSLog (@"list = %@", milkprice);
for (NSString *milk in milkprice) {
    sum += [milk floatValue];
    NSLog (@"sum = %f", sum);
}

NSLog (@"total = %f", sum);
```

BTW - why are you using strings for the numbers?